# How to insert, update Oracle fields(nvarchar, nclob) into Chinese using Mybatis

Tags: oracle11g, localization

I set the REQUEST filed into Chinese, but it shows as "????????" in the database.

How can I config it?

SAMPLE TEXT : 獎,為,售,產,呆,扣

- Tomcat / Mybatis
- Oracle 11g : NSL_CHARACTERSET - MSWIN949, NSL_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET - UTF16
- Target field type : nvarchar2, nclob

Answer (score 0):

e.g. table1 having single coulmn

```
Insert into table1 values (N'獎,為,售,產,呆,扣')
```

Comment: Try but result same...T^T

Answer (score 0):

Your Oracle database is configured to use the MSWIN949 character set, which is the Hangul (Korean) character set. Once installed, you can't change the character set the database uses.